# Trigger from plpgSQL to MySQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql, triggers

I have question about triggers.
I've created a function in plpgSQL for PostgreSQL, but, now I need to do this in MySQL. I tried almost everything and I don't know how to to this. Does anybody knows what to do and help me?

Here is the code in in plpgSQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION provjera_rezultata() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
    DECLARE
    neodigrane_utakmice INT;

    BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO neodigrane_utakmice
    FROM utakmice AS u
        JOIN momcadi AS m1
            ON m1.momcad_ID = u.momcad_a
        JOIN momcadi AS m2
            ON m2.momcad_ID = u.momcad_b
    WHERE rezultat IS NULL;

    IF neodigrane_utakmice > 0 THEN
        RAISE NOTICE 'Broj utakmica bez rezultata je %', neodigrane_utakmice;
    END IF;

    RETURN NEW;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Also, I don't know what to use in MySQL for "RAISE NOTICE" from PostgreSQL.

I did this, but I get error :(

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER provjera_rezultata
    AFTER INSERT ON utakmice FOR EACH ROW
    DECLARE broj INTEGER;

BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO broj
    FROM utakmice AS u
        JOIN momcadi AS m1
            ON m1.momcad_ID = u.momcad_a
        JOIN momcadi AS m2
            ON m2.momcad_ID = u.momcad_b
    WHERE rezultat IS NULL;

    IF broj > 0 THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Postoje utakmice bez konacnog rezultata!';
    END IF;
END $$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner parts of your code could remain basically the same as it does.

Triggers are created with [`CREATE TRIGGER`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-trigger.html).

Notices in MySQL are called [signals](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/signal.html). You do

```
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'An error occurred';
```

Comment: I insert MySQL code in question, but I get errors :(

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL you declare variables inside the begin-end. This code gives me no syntax error:

```
# test tables
CREATE TABLE utakmice(
    momcad_a INT,
    momcad_b INT,
    rezultat INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (momcad_a, momcad_b)
);
CREATE TABLE momcadi(
    momcad_ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
);


DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER provjera_rezultata
    AFTER INSERT ON utakmice FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE broj INTEGER;
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO broj
    FROM utakmice AS u
        JOIN momcadi AS m1
            ON m1.momcad_ID = u.momcad_a
        JOIN momcadi AS m2
            ON m2.momcad_ID = u.momcad_b
    WHERE rezultat IS NULL;

    IF broj > 0 THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Postoje utakmice bez konacnog rezultata!';
    END IF;
END $$
```

I know this post is old but I somehow came here and it was missing an answer. For future problems this answer can be helpful.